# What happens when there are nulls in the whole number column in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

I have a Power BI model that has whole number values in the order_quantity column.

But some of the values are null. I can replace them with 0 or leave them as it is. What difference does it make in reports?

Answer (score 1):

> What difference does it make in reports?

Nulls are excluded from all aggregates.  Zeros affect Count, Average, etc.

Comment: To tack onto this - null is the absence of data, whereas zero is a value. I often see people substituting nulls with zeroes where they absolutely should not do so, since they do not understand the implication on their calculations.